# Selecting all pixels from Pixel Inspector?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, graph, copy, pixel

[image]

While using the Pixel Inspector, whenever I click "copy all values" it only copies values that you can see on the screen. Anyone know a solution? I need all the values to count the number of times 1, 2, and 0 appear on the graph.

Comment: Maybe someone will have a better solution, but from what I can tell, it looks like what you might need is the  [Zonal Histogram](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Zonal_Histogram/009z000000w6000000/) tool instead of the Pixel Inspector.  The Pixel Inspector is really only useful at extremely zoomed in extents and is not designed to show the data for an entire raster.  Unfortunately, the Zonal Histogram tool is only available with the Spatial Analyst extension.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count number of unique pixels in current extent you may do this (fast and dirty, but it works):

1. Zoom to your custom extent.
2. `Export data` (right click on raster in `Table Of Content`).
3. Make sure option `Data Frame (Current)` and save it on the disk.
4. Go to `Layer Proprties` in `Symbology` tab and select `unique values`
5. On the picture below there are 65 pixels with value `11786` in the whole raster subset.

[image]